# Why @PostConstruct doesn't work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a simple EJB , and when i run it through my standalone client every thing is working well,
But once i add an interceptor, The @PostConstruct in the EJB stops working:

package interceptor;

```
public class LogInterceptor {

@PostConstruct
public void init(InvocationContext context) {
    System.out.println(new Date().toString() +" Entered interceptor");
}

@PreDestroy
public void aboutToBeRemoved(InvocationContext context) {
    System.out.println(new Date().toString() + " Leaving interceptor");
}

@AroundInvoke
public Object gettingToBusiness(InvocationContext context) {

    String methodName = context.getMethod().getName();
    System.out.println("The method name is: " +methodName);

    if (methodName.equals("add")) {

    }
    try {
        return context.proceed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

My test client:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){
    InitialContext ctx=getInitialContext();
    ListRemote stub=null;
    try {
        stub = (ListRemote)ctx.lookup("ejb:/Lab12/ListEJB!interceptor.ListRemote?stateful");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Lookup Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Adding data");
    stub.add("Hello");
    stub.add("-");
    stub.add("World");
    stub.add("!!!");
    System.out.println("Getting data :");
    for(Object o:stub.getAll()){
        System.out.print(o+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("Removing '-' element");
    stub.remove(1);
    System.out.println("Getting data again:");
    for(Object o:stub.getAll()){
        System.out.print(o+" ");
    }
    stub.destroy();
}

public static InitialContext getInitialContext(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES , "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            try {
        return new InitialContext(properties);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot generate InitialContext");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

My EJB:

```
@Stateful(name="ListEJB")
@Interceptors({LogInterceptor.class})
public class ListBean implements ListRemote{
private ArrayList<Serializable> list;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println("In it init ---------------------------------------------------");
    list=new ArrayList<Serializable>();
}
public void add(Serializable object){
    System.out.println("Currently in the list is: " +list);

    System.out.println("The object is: " +object);
    list.add(object);
    System.out.println("Added");
}
public Serializable get(int index){
    return list.get(index);
}
public void remove(int index){
    list.remove(index);
}
public Object[] getAll(){
    return list.toArray();
}
@Remove
public void destroy(){
    list=null;
}

}
```

Why does it disables my EJB @PostConstruct ?

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? It's not getting invoked?

Comment: Yes, it is not getting invoked

Comment: who is going to handle the @PostConstruct? You do not have a container

Comment: @Eugene based on the code, it seems to be in a JBoss container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(InvocationContext context) {
    System.out.println(new Date().toString() +" Entered interceptor");
}
```

You are intercepting the PostConstruct of the original EJB and not letting it pass. If you want to pass it through to the target EJB, you need to call proceed:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(InvocationContext context) {
    System.out.println(new Date().toString() +" Entered interceptor");
    context.proceed();
}
```

Same applies for your PreDestroy. Basically it applies to all intercepted methods. See the [EJB3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/), section 12.5 (page 308):

> Interceptor methods must always call InvocationContext.proceed() or no
>   subsequent interceptor methods or bean business method or lifecycle
>   callback methods will be invoked.